# Trying to understand why multimap constructs / desctructs like it does

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, multimap

I have a printout of all the "addresses" for you first. The thing im trying to understand is why is it allocating at the time. I have constructed a multimap with a String and an Object, in the constructor & destructor of this object I have a printout when they are called.

First Question: Is it copying the Object?
Second Question: Why do i see more destructors than constructors?
Third Question: I never get the address listed in any constructor which we see below (last 5)

Thanks for helping me to understand this *construction/destruction in multimap* .

Oliver

```
    std::multimap <string, TestObject> m;

for(int i = 0; i < 5 ;i++){

    TestObjectone("test", i);

    m.insert(pair<string, TestObject>(("a" + i), one));
    cout << "Single Iteration" <<  i << endl;

}
```

Param constructor test0 0x22ff24
Destructor is called TestObject: test0 0x22ff08
Destructor is called TestObject: test0 0x22ff18
Single Iteration0
Destructor is called TestObject: test0 0x22ff24
Param constructor test1 0x22ff24
Destructor is called TestObject: test1 0x22ff08
Destructor is called TestObject: test1 0x22ff18
Single Iteration1
Destructor is called TestObject: test1 0x22ff24
Param constructor test2 0x22ff24
Destructor is called TestObject: test2 0x22ff08
Destructor is called TestObject: test2 0x22ff18
Single Iteration2
Destructor is called TestObject: test2 0x22ff24
Param constructor test3 0x22ff24
Destructor is called TestObject: test3 0x22ff08
Destructor is called TestObject: test3 0x22ff18
Single Iteration3
Destructor is called TestObject: test3 0x22ff24
Param constructor test4 0x22ff24
Destructor is called TestObject: test4 0x22ff08
Destructor is called TestObject: test4 0x22ff18
Single Iteration4
Destructor is called TestObject: test4 0x22ff24

Destructor is called TestObject: test4 0x482f6c
Destructor is called TestObject: test3 0x482efc
Destructor is called TestObject: test0 0x482dd4
Destructor is called TestObject: test2 0x482e8c
Destructor is called TestObject: test1 0x482e1c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First question:**
yes, STL-container have a value semantic and your objects are copied.

**Second Question:**
probably because your Copy Constructor has no debug prints. If you have not implemented your own, custom made copy-ctor, then the defaults copy-ctr will be used.

**Third Question:**
You see the destructor calls of the copy constructed objects (as also jkrok mentions in the comments)

Comment: +1. For third question you could add: The last 5 destructors are of the objects which were copy-constructed when inserted in `m` and are called when `m` goes out of scope.

Comment: so multimap will do a memcpy and after that call a destructor, i ask because i have no copy constructor (i would assume that copying the memory block would be the default copy constructor?) while looking at the current behaviour

Comment: @OliverStutz: The compiler-generated copy ctor for a class will call the copy ctor for all its members. In your case, it will call the copy ctor for `string` and `TestObject`. This is the correct thing to do; you can't `memcpy` a `string`.

Comment: @MSalters thanks for clarifying, i assumed that it would do a memcpy because the effect of a "shallow" copy can be visible if a pointer within the custom class is added without any copy functionality, but I believe its not doing it recursively, please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Oliver: The compiler-generated copy ctor _is_ doing it recursively, but copying a pointer is shallow in C++. That's true both for pointers inside and outside classes.